# $x^{n}$ is Lipschitz for bounded domain

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing, solution-verification, lipschitz-functions

I have been trying to solve the followig problem:

**Problem:** Show that $f(x)=x^{n}$ is Lipschitz if $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where X is a bounded set.

**What have i tried so far?**

Well, since X is bounded, there exists a constant $M > 0$ such that $|\mathrm{x}| < M$, $\forall x \in X$. With that in mind, i tried writing:

$$
|f(x)-f(y)|=\left|x^{n}-y^{n}\right|=
$$
$$\left|(x-y)\left(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2} y+\cdots+x y^{n-2}+y^{n-1}\right)\right| \leq
$$

$$
\leq |x-y| (\left|x^{n-1}\right|+\left|x^{n-2} \cdot y\right|+\ldots+\left|x y^{n-2}\right|+\left|y^{n-1}\right|)
$$

Now, since terms such as $|x^{n-1}|$ satisfy $|x|^{n - 1} \leq M^{n-1}$ i should be able to bound the power terms and obtain an inequality of the form: $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq c|x-y|$$

Is the ideia correct? Can someone help me write the answer more precisely?

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: You are on the right track. Notice that

$$|x^{n-1}| + |x^{n-2}y| + \ldots + |xy^{n-2}| + |y^{n-1}| \leq nM^{n-1} $$

Comment: Why are there n terms? I tried to figure that out before, but could not argue properly

Comment: It is easier to use MVT.

Comment: @Lucas Observe that

$$|x^{n-1}|  = |x|^{n-1} \leq M^{n-1}$$

Similarly, observe that

$$|x^{n-2}y| = |x|^{n-2}|y| \leq M^{n-2}M = M^{n-1}$$

Since there are $n$ suchlike terms, we get the upper bound $nM^{n-1}$.

Comment: Nice! But why are there n suchlike terms?

Comment: Because the exponent of $x$ lies between $0$ and $n-1$.

Comment: Besides finishing by bounding the terms like you gently explained, is there anything else i should take care of to write a clean proof?

Comment: Besides such detail, it is pretty good as it is.